# Enable Free Trial Offer On Subscription Of Application In Google Play Store

Tags: android, mobile, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

I created the Subscription and the Free trial Offer for 7 days on Play Console. But when I use a new Android device to Install the App on Google Play Store, I can't see the Free trial for my Application. Could you please see the Screenshot and support me for enable the free trial offer on Google Play Store? Thanks All!

[image: My Subscription On Play Console]

[image: My Offer on Subscription]

[image: My App on Google. Don't display a free trial for users who can install the Application]

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem and finally, I found the solution.

Recently, Google migrated to a new billing system, so trials and discounts are no longer part of the subscription. For some reason, they are different products. However, they have the identical product id as the main subscription item.

So when you are loading a product by id calling *queryProductDetails()* in response productDetails you should receive not just 1 item as before, but several items with the same id but with different tokens.
And depending on which item you send to *buyNonConsumable()* you will get different options in the Google Play purchase dialog, despite they have the same product id. The trial subscription will be with a "Free" price, a longer token, and most likely the first in the list.

Comment: how to disable the trial offer?